# serialization and desrialization variable deletion

Tags: java, serialization

Suppose I serialize the below class (by putting a value to field `x`, say `5`), and before doing the deserialization, I remove field `x` and put a new field `y` (`int` or `float`), what will be the result?

I believe deserialization is done successfully and value of field `y` will be default, is this correct?

If this is correct, where will the value if `x` will go in the transition from persistent object to stateful object at serialization time?

```
public class Cat implements Serializable{    
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4231235177539824282L;  
  int x;
}
```

before deserialization:

```
public class Cat implements Serializable{    
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4231235177539824282L;  
  float/int y;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The serialization spec details the inner workings of field deserialization (you can find it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html)

If you browse through the "readObject method" section it states:

> Any field of the object that does not appear in the stream is set to
>   its default value. Values that appear in the stream, but not in the
>   object, are discarded. This occurs primarily when a later version of a
>   class has written additional fields that do not occur in the earlier
>   version.

So in essence, the field 'x' will have some value in the stream, but will be discarded and the field 'y' will be set to 0 (default value) since it does not appear in the stream.

Comment: both deleting field in old generation and adding a field in new genration are practically same.they both would set default value in new generation then how one is compatible and one is incompatible?

Answer (score 2):

Jain007, I think you will probably get an exception in this case as you have 'deleted' a field.

FYI, the following are the incompatible changes that might result in an exception:
 - Delete fields 
 - Change class hierarchy 
 - Change non-static to static
 - Change non-transient to transient
 - Change type of a primitive field

While following are the compatible changes that wont affect the deserialization process:
 - Add fields 
 - Change a field from static to non-static 
 - Change a field from transient to non-transient 
 - Add classes to the object tree

Comment: as much as i checked on jdk5, with a defined serialVersionUID this is not the case - there is no exception  but then also i am not sure, as i am also not convinced and want to know what exactly happens

Answer (score 1):

Serialized data contains of variable names and signature which will be used during deserialization. The y will be default, because it was not described in serialized data. the x value will be missed such as new Cat class does not contains variable with suitable signature.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html